# spring boot @refreshscope doesn't update datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to update DB datasource if the environment variable for DB.URL changes. Below is my class,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties(value="myapp")
public class MyApp {
@Value("${myapp.db.url}")
String databaseURL;

@Value("${myapp.db.username}")
String databaseUsername;

@Value("${myapp.db.password}")
String databasePassword;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}

@Bean
@RefreshScope
@Primary
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(databaseUsername).password(databasePassword).url(databaseURL)
            .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver").build();
}
}
```

But when I update environment DB.URL it doesn't make request to new DB.

I have referred the documentation as it is possible to update datasource, 
http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope

What is missing in my class?

Comment: Can you attempt moving this into it's own configuration class and not the main spring boot application? You may also need the `RefreshScope` on the configuraiton itself

Comment: Hi @DarrenForsythe If I move datasource configuration to a separate class with _@RefreshScope_. Project cannot build as the spring-clould-config-client cannot detect the datasource. Below is the exception,Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration.<init>(HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java:195)

Comment: are you putting it within the same package as the application?

Comment: Hi @DarrenForsythe, Yes I'm putting it in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this **@RefreshScope** annotation on class context **MyApp**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationProperties(value="myapp")
@RefreshScope
public class MyApp {
  ...
}
```

And also, make sure to do request POST on service: `http://{your.api.url}/actuator/refresh`, in order to refresh it after you had changed the properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you add **@RefreshScope** to class without removing from method. Then **@Value** variables will be refreshed. And datasource will change.